# Java/GPars - my thread pool seems to get "clogged"

Tags: java, groovy, concurrency, process, gpars

What I'm doing: I'm going through a table of companies in a dbase... each company has a text `description` field, and inside that field there can be a number of hyperlinks (rarely more than 4).  What I want to do is to test these links, using `curl`, for a "bad" response (typically 404, but anything non-200 will be of interest).

Incidentally, this is applicable to Java as much as Groovy, no doubt, and persons of either persuasion might be interested to know that the underlying thread pool class used here by GPars (Groovy parallelism) is `ForkJoinPool`.

Having gathered up these URLs using a `Matcher` using the `Pattern`  `/(https?:.*?)\)/` I get a map `descripURLs` of "url" --> "name of company". Then I use `withPool` with a large capacity (because of the intrinsic latency of waiting for responses, obviously) like so:

```
startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() 
AtomicInteger nRequest = new AtomicInteger()
AtomicInteger nResponsesReceived = new AtomicInteger()
poolObject = null
resultP = withPool( 50 ){ pool ->
    poolObject = pool
    descripURLs.eachParallel{ url, name ->
        int localNRequest = nRequest.incrementAndGet()
        Process process = checkURL( url )

        def response
        try {
            //// with the next line TIME PASSES in this Thread...
            response = process.text
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println "$e"
        }
        // NB this line doesn't appear to make much difference
        process.destroyForcibly()
        nResponses = nResponsesReceived.incrementAndGet()
        int nRequestsNowMade = nRequest.get()
        if( response.trim() != '200' ) {
            println "\n*** request $localNRequest BAD RESPONSE\nname $name url $url\nresponse |$response|" +
                "\n$nRequestsNowMade made, outstanding ${nRequestsNowMade - nResponses}"
             // NB following line may of course not be printed immmediately after the above line, due to parallelism
            println "\nprocess poolSize $pool.poolSize, queuedTaskCount $pool.queuedTaskCount," +
                " queuedSubmissionCount? $pool.queuedSubmissionCount"   
        }
        println "time now ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis}, activeThreadCount $pool.activeThreadCount"
    }
    println "END OF withPool iterations"
    println "pool $pool class ${pool.class.simpleName}, activeThreadCount $pool.activeThreadCount"
    pool.shutdownNow()
}

println "resultP $resultP class ${resultP.class.simpleName}"
println "pool $poolObject class ${poolObject.class.simpleName}"
println "pool shutdown? $poolObject.shutdown"

def checkURL( url ) {
    def process =  "curl -LI $url -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s".execute()
    // this appears necessary... otherwise potentially you can have processes hanging around forever
    process.waitForOrKill( 8000 ) // 8 s to get a reponse
    process.addShutdownHook{
        println "shutdown on url $url"
    }
    process
}
```

What I observe with a 50-Thread pool as above is that 500 URLs will take 20 s to complete. I've experimented with smaller and larger pools, and 100 seems to make no difference, but 25 seems slower, and 10 more like 40 s to complete.  Timings are also remarkably consistent from run to run for the same pool size.

What I don't understand is that the `Process`es' shutdown hooks only run at the very end of the closure... for all 500 `Process`es! This is not to say that 500 actual processes are hanging around on the machine: using task manager I can see that the number of `curl.exe` processes at any one time is relatively small.

At the same time I observe from the `println`s here that the active thread count here starts at 50, but then declines throughout the run, reaching 3 (typically) by the end.  AND YET... I can also observe that the final requests are only being added very near the end of the run.

This leads me to wonder whether the thread pool is in some way being "clogged up" by this "unfinished business" of these "zombie" `Process`es... I would expect the final requests (of the 500 made) to be made well before the end of the run.  Is there any way I can shut down these `Process`es earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Java nor Groovy support a method `addShutdownHook` on child `Process` instances.

The only method [`addShutdownHook`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-) that Java supports is on the `Runtime` instance. This adds a hook to run **at JVM shutdown**.

Groovy adds a convenience [`addShutdownHook()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#addShutdownHook(groovy.lang.Closure)) to the `Object` class so that you don't have to write `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(..)`, but this changes nothing on the underlying mechanism: these hooks are only executed at JVM shutdown.

Because the closures that you add with `process.addShutdownHook` most probably keep references to the `process` instance, these will be kept alive until JVM shutdown (the Java objects, but not the OS processes)

Comment: Ah... thanks for that clarification. You may have found the key here: I just commented out that addShutdownHook stuff and timing seems to be ever so slightly improved... perhaps because the GC can then get to work??? This is kind of beyond my paygrade, as you may imagine. In fact the final requests are still being made very late in the run...

Comment: I just did some memory tests during the run (`Runtime.freeMemory` etc.).  These tend to suggest that a `Process` instance doesn't have a significant memory footprint... Not that that's conclusive of course.

Comment: @mikerodent I'm not sure whether `GParsPool` (using ForkJoinPool) or  `GParsExecutorsPool` (using Executors) is the better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... that is actually giving better timings... the final requests seem to occur a longer time before the end, and the "outstanding" `Process` counts seem to make more sense.  I've only been using Groovy for 4 months or so, in Java I have tended to use fixed thread pools from `Executors`' static methods, so am also a bit more familiar with it...